# python redis queue enqueues only 1 job

Tags: python, redis, queue

A super simple use case - put image download jobs with redis queue

```
# main.py
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue
from tasks import download_asset

queue = Queue(connection=Redis())
if __name__ == '__main__':
  image_urls = ['https://image.com/image1.png', 'https://image.com/image2.png']
  job1 = queue.enqueue(download_asset, image_urls[0], result_ttl=5000)
  print job1
  job2 = queue.enqueue(download_asset, image_urls[1], result_ttl=5000)
  print job2
  import time; time.sleep(3)
  print job1.result
  print job2.result
```

when I run `python main.py`,

```
<Job 8de87fc3-0480-4181-bb57-182773eaa4dd: tasks.download_asset('https://image.com/image1.png')>
<Job 6e334cc7-e2a5-46cb-b28a-7f8df6921c44: tasks.download_asset('https://image.com/image2.png')>
None
None
```

the results are none but I do see the 2nd image downloaded into the folder.
and in the worker log

```
01:48:26 default: tasks.download_asset('https://image.com/image2.png') (6e334cc7-e2a5-46cb-b28a-7f8df6921c44)
download image
01:48:26 Job OK
01:48:26 Result is kept for 5000 seconds
01:48:26
01:48:26 *** Listening on default...
```

only 1 job was processed

Workers were stared using `rq worker`.

download code:

```
def download_asset(url):
  print 'download image'
  media_file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
  with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.write(media_file.read())
```

one thing I noticed was if I put sleep.time(3) between the enqueue, the 1st still does NOT get enqueued

Comment: where are the image_urls defined?

Comment: right above enqueue

Comment: How do you know only one object is being queued?

Comment: edited the questions, sorry should have been clearer

Comment: Where is the download code? It seems that when the job.result is none it hasn't completed the job yet according to the api docs

Comment: added the download code, I think it just returns whatever the function returns in this case it's None

Comment: Can you return true when done from the download code if successful and false of it fails? It's pretty useful to be able to see what succeeded and failed.

Comment: just tried it, in that case it prints None, True which means the 1st job wasn't executed

Comment: Does your worker keep running when the main function stops?

Comment: ya, it does return to wait for job in default queue.

Comment: Does it show up in the redis server? Task 1 that is

Comment: it doesn't which makes no sense

Comment: I'm assuming you aren't running on Windows.

Comment: actually figured it out lol, I have another worker for another project running that's also pulling from the same redis queue. lolololol

Comment: If you run a len(queue) after adding the first job what do you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

silly me, I have another worker from another project that's pulling jobs from the same redis queue